# SQL Error Handling for Select statements

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a multiple select statement combined to gether using UNION ALL.
for Eg:

```
Select col1,col2,...,coln from A
UNION ALL
Select Col1,Col2,...,coln from B
```

one of the Column in the 2nd table is having wrong value and i get below error when executing the query.

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Am having diffucltie to identify which column/row is causing the issue has it has many columns and the error does not specifically say anything. Can some please provide me a example where i can track down the error. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: What are the datatypes of your columns? They must be identical in the first and second query

Comment: @bluefeet..Yes i agree with you....am assuming they are the same ....but there are like 300 columns so its tough to track down which one is causing the issue

Comment: My suggestion would be to look at the create table for both tables and be sure that the datatypes are the same.  That is going to be the only way to try and debug this.  Or remove columns one by one from the query to see which throws the error

Comment: Do the columns have the same name in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this script that compares the metadata for these two SELECTs. To get metadata information I used [sp_describe_cursor_columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182755%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) system procedure (that is not so nice to use - true; available within SQL Server 2008) because [sp_describe_first_result_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx) is available starting with SQL Server 2012.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Metadata TABLE (
    select_num tinyint NOT NULL,
        check (select_num IN (1,2)),
    ordinal_position int not null,
        primary key (select_num, ordinal_position),
    column_name sysname,
    column_size int,
    data_type_sql smallint,
    column_precision tinyint,
    column_scale tinyint
)

DECLARE 
    @column_name sysname,
    @ordinal_position int,
    @column_characteristics_flags int,
    @column_size int,
    @data_type_sql smallint,
    @column_precision tinyint,
    @column_scale tinyint,
    @order_position int,
    @order_direction varchar(1),
    @hidden_column smallint,
    @columnid int,
    @objectid int,
    @dbid int,
    @dbname sysname

DECLARE @ReturnSelect CURSOR

-- Metadata for the first query
DECLARE CursorSelect1 CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY 
FOR 
SELECT  TOP(0) ...
FROM    A ... 

OPEN    CursorSelect1

EXEC sp_describe_cursor_columns @cursor_return=@ReturnSelect OUTPUT, @cursor_source='local', @cursor_identity=N'CursorSelect1'

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM @ReturnSelect INTO 
        @column_name,
        @ordinal_position,
        @column_characteristics_flags,
        @column_size,
        @data_type_sql,
        @column_precision,
        @column_scale,
        @order_position,
        @order_direction,
        @hidden_column,
        @columnid,
        @objectid,
        @dbid,
        @dbname
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  @Metadata (select_num, ordinal_position, column_name, data_type_sql, column_size, column_precision, column_scale)
        VALUES  (1, @ordinal_position, @column_name, @data_type_sql, @column_size, @column_precision, @column_scale); -- First SELECT
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
END

CLOSE   CursorSelect1
DEALLOCATE CursorSelect1
CLOSE   @ReturnSelect
DEALLOCATE @ReturnSelect
-- End of Metadata for the first query

-- Metadata for the second query
DECLARE CursorSelect2 CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY 
FOR 
SELECT  TOP(0) ...
FROM    B ...

OPEN    CursorSelect2

EXEC sp_describe_cursor_columns @cursor_return=@ReturnSelect OUTPUT, @cursor_source='local', @cursor_identity=N'CursorSelect2'

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM @ReturnSelect INTO 
        @column_name,
        @ordinal_position,
        @column_characteristics_flags,
        @column_size,
        @data_type_sql,
        @column_precision,
        @column_scale,
        @order_position,
        @order_direction,
        @hidden_column,
        @columnid,
        @objectid,
        @dbid,
        @dbname
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  @Metadata (select_num, ordinal_position, column_name, data_type_sql, column_size, column_precision, column_scale)
        VALUES  (2, @ordinal_position, @column_name, @data_type_sql, @column_size, @column_precision, @column_scale); -- Second SELECT
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        BREAK
    END
END

CLOSE   CursorSelect2
DEALLOCATE CursorSelect2
-- End of Metadata for the second query

CLOSE   @ReturnSelect
DEALLOCATE @ReturnSelect

SELECT  s1.*, s2.*
FROM (
    SELECT m.*, t.name AS user_type_name 
    FROM @Metadata m JOIN sys.types t ON m.data_type_sql=t.user_type_id 
    WHERE select_num=1
) s1 -- metadata for the first SELECT
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT m.*, t.name AS user_type_name 
    FROM @Metadata m JOIN sys.types t ON m.data_type_sql=t.user_type_id 
    WHERE select_num=2
) s2 -- metadata for the second SELECT
ON      s1.ordinal_position=s2.ordinal_position
WHERE   s1.data_type_sql<>s2.data_type_sql -- It compares the data type for every column from these two SELECT queries 

/*
-- or 
SELECT  s1.*, s2.*
FROM    (SELECT m.*, t.name AS user_type_name FROM @Metadata m JOIN sys.types t ON m.data_type_sql=t.user_type_id WHERE select_num=1) s1 -- metadata for the first SELECT
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT m.*, t.name AS user_type_name FROM @Metadata m JOIN sys.types t ON m.data_type_sql=t.user_type_id WHERE select_num=2) s2 -- metadata for the second SELECT
ON      s1.ordinal_position=s2.ordinal_position
WHERE   s1.ordinal_position=s2.ordinal_position
AND     s1.data_type_sql<>s2.data_type_sql -- It compares the data type for every column from these two SELECT queries 
OR      s1.ordinal_position IS NOT NULL AND s2.ordinal_position IS NULL
OR      s1.ordinal_position IS NULL AND s2.ordinal_position IS NOT NULL
*/
```